# How to get the url on the magnific popup API on open event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, magnific-popup

How can I get the url being opened with the [Magnific popup API](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api)? I want to add it the `window.location.hash` in the open event callback:

```
<a href="page-title" class="mfp">Lorem ipsum</a>

$('.mfp').magnificPopup({

  callbacks: {
    open: function() {
     var url = this.url
     window.location.hash += '-'+url
    }
  }
});
```

I tried using `this.url` but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:

first, searched through `console.log($.magnificPopup.instance)` and finally found

`this.currItem.src`